# connecting to RF reader insecurely using bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, insecure-connection

I am trying to connect insecurely using bluetooth to a RFreader. 
I tried using the bluetooth chat example provided in the sample projects. I am using android 2.3 and above for this.

I have encountered many links for using

```
createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()
```

along with

```
listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID)
```

1. I have changed Bluetooth chat example according to my need.
2. Initially it shows up the list of scanned devices(RF reader shows up).
3. After selecting a device, the `connectThread` will be invoked. It will create the `BluetoothSocket` using `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()`.
4. Then I am starting the thread which cancels discovery and calls `bluetoothSocket.connect()`.

But, it is failing here giving an `**IOException:Service discovery failed**`. I have removed the code for `AcceptThread()` which listens for connections, since I am explicitly connecting by selecting a device from list of scanned devices.

Am I doing any mistake ? Is there any other procedure for connecting to non-UI bluetooth devices ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the UUID you are using is correct and should be the same at the Clinet and the Server sides.

Ensure that on the RF reader side it is waiting for incoming connection ? i.e there is an equivalent of the listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord().

Comment: Ok. So, for the RF reader also has a UUID which has to be used in android app ? How should we check if the RF reader is waiting for connection ? So, the only means for establishing a connection for non-UI devices is, they should be waiting like a server. Am I correct for the last statement ?

Comment: So, we will have to make use of UUID used within the RF reader ? Where can we get this UUID from ? Device manfacturer ?